# Segmentation fault in a remove spaces program

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program from removing spaces in a string in C. I tried to debug using `gdb` but I guess I am not very knowledgable in using that tool. My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void RemoveSpaces(char * str){
    char *var1, *var2;
    var1 =  str; var2 = str;
    while(*var1 != '\0'){
        if(*var1 != ' '){
            *var2 = *var1;
            var2++;
        }
        var1++;
    }
    *var2 = '\0';
}

int main(){
    char *str = "abc de";
    printf("Before: %s\n", str);
    RemoveSpaces(str);
    printf("After: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to set watch on var1 and var2 but I get SIGSEGV on line where `*var2 = *var1;` I looked for some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726302/removing-spaces-from-a-string-in-c) before writing my own. Of course, the answer states that its untested but I am doing a similar statement on the line where I get error. Why wouldn't (thereotically) `*i = *j++;` give an error while `*var2 = *var1;` would? (I don't want someone to remove my error. I just want to know why I might be getting this error so that I can avoid it in future. )

Comment: Yeah, because you are trying to modify a string constant in-place. (it's not an accident it's a **constant.**) If you initialize an array with it instead (`char str[] = "abc de";`), it will work. But there are a lot of duplicates of this very same problem already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a string literal - change:

```
char *str = "abc de";
```

to:

```
char str[] = "abc de";
```

Comment: If someone is curious as to what difference does `char str[]` makes, please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c