# How to remove white spaces from String in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Could anyone here tell me how to get rid of the white spaces of the String(a)!!

```
 String a = "GET /?led=21 HTTP/1.1";
 void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print(a); 
  }
 void loop() {

 }
```

Comment: Arduino uses C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726302/removing-spaces-from-a-string-in-c and use Serial.print(RemoveSpaces(a));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Arduino you can replace strings by modifying the existing string like this:

```
a.replace(" ", "");
```

[Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/replace/):

> The String replace() function allows you to replace all instances of a given character with another character. You can also use replace to replace substrings of a String with a different substring.

Comment: Correct, Arduino behaves a little bit different than the STL. I've fixed it. thanks!

Comment: this is not working on arduino IDE 1.8.15