# Delete space error in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#define SIZE 100

int main(void){

    char str[SIZE];
    char str2[SIZE];
    int i;
    int len;
    gets(str);

    len = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; str[i] != NULL; i++) {
        if (str[i] != ' '){
            str2[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){

        printf("%c", str2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It returns the following error:

[image: screenshot]

What is the problem?

I just want to copy some elements in *str* to *str2* without spaces, but when I run, it has got some weird letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Spaces from a String in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726302/removing-spaces-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Note that `gets` is [obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used/4309845).

Comment: @WeatherVane more importantly, ***dangerous!!!***

Comment: It seems also that you are mixing up `NULL` which is a null pointer, and the null character which is usually designated by `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3):

You need two index variables

- one to go through `str`
- one to tell where to write next to `str2`

code:

```
 len = strlen(str);
 int j;
 for (i=0, j=0 ; str[i] != '\0' ; i++) {
    if (str[i] != ' '){
        str2[j++] = str[i]; // store to str2 and increment j
    }
}
```

Then store a final `\0` to `str2` at index `j`

```
str2[j] = '\0';
```

Finally, to print the result, you can do that one shot

```
printf("%s\n", str2);
```

instead of printing one char at a time.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! May i ask why i have to use two variables? Why don't i just use 'i' to tell where to go and store elemts?

Comment: Note that `NULL` is a pointer value, not a string terminator and has been changed here to `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: @이지웅 because `str2` is *uninitialised* and you are skipping elements which remain so.

Comment: @이지웅 Take a piece of paper and write "how are you", you write "how" to str2, then the space, you skip it, but what is at `str2[3]`? Garbage because you skipped that character in `str2` too. Using `j` allows you to track where is the next non-space character supposed to be written in `str2`.

Answer (score 3):

For starters these headers

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

can be removed because neither declaration from the headers is used in the program.

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard any more. Instead use standard C function `fgets`.

When `str` is copied in `str2` you have to use separate index to access characters in str2 because some characters from `str` are not copied. Otherwise the array `str2` will contain gaps. As result you can not use the previous value of the variable `len` with the array `str2`.

Also it is desirable not to copy any other white space characters.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE    100

int main(void)
{
    char str[SIZE];
    char str2[SIZE];

    fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

    const char *p = str;
    char *p2 = str2;

    do
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
        {
            *p2++ = *p;
        }
    } while ( *p++ );

    for ( p2 = str2; *p2; ++p2 )
    {
        printf( "%c", *p2 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might be

```
Hello   World
HelloWorld
```

If you do not study yet pointers then the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE    100

int main(void)
{
    char str[SIZE];
    char str2[SIZE];

    fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    do
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )str[i] ) )
        {
            str2[j++] = str[i];
        }
    } while ( str[i++] );

    for ( j = 0; str2[j]; ++j )
    {
        printf( "%c", str2[j] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but it is little bit complicate for me to understand.. i m not good at that 'pointer' things..  is better to get practice on using pointer?