# keep only one space between words in a string

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function in C that removes all multiply spaces in a string.

For example:

```
"  some    random       string   " => "some random string"
```

I want a void function to get a string and without changing it just print it.
I saw some previous threads about this question but didn't find the exact thing I need.

Comment: What have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Spaces from a String in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726302/removing-spaces-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: You write "I'm trying to write a function...". So I suppose you have written a function that doesn't work for some reason. If you want help you need to [edit] your question and show your code _there_

Comment: You also write: " I saw some previous threads about this question but didn't find the exact thing I need". Maybe you should tell us _what_ exact thing you need.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are going to need to be clearer than that. 'get a string' from where?  'I want a void function' why this constraint?  If the string getting fails, how is the fail to be notified to the caller?  'didn't find the exact thing I need' - see @MichaelWalz above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starting example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_str_but_no_mul_spaces(char* str)
{
    // eat pre-found whitespaces
    while(*str && *str == ' ')
        str++;
    while(*str)
    {
        // If this is not the prelast char AND
        // the next char is not a space OR
        // the current char is not a space AND next char is a space
        if(*(str + 1) != '\0' && (*(str + 1) != ' ' || (*str != ' ' && *(str + 1) == ' ')))
            putchar(*str);
        str++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    print_str_but_no_mul_spaces("  some    random       string   ");
    return 0;
}
```

which should inspire you to keep on, and make you remember to always show some research-effort before posting a question. Good luck!